Kubernetes nodeport not accessible
I have installed Grafana on Kubernetes. The installation is ok. When I do port forwarding, I can access Grafana dashboard. However, when I try to access using nodeport, web times out.
My Grafana service is running
monitoring    my-grafana             ClusterIP   10.92.253.89    <none>        80/TCP                   21

my grafana pod is ok too
monitoring    my-grafana-5b7dbf77b7-bzhxb                             1/1     Running   0             21d

my nodeport file
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: web-srv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: my-grafana-5b7dbf77b7-bzhxb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8090
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31000

my nodes are working ok too
NAME                                     STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                KERNEL-VERSION                 CONTAINER-RUNTIME
prd-scl-it-k8-grafana1-cabd0e-master-0   Ready    control-plane,master   21d   v1.28.5   172.20.8.129   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1160.108.1.el7.x86_64   containerd://1.6.16
prd-scl-it-k8-grafana1-cabd0e-master-1   Ready    control-plane,master   21d   v1.28.5   172.20.8.197   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1160.108.1.el7.x86_64   containerd://1.6.16
prd-scl-it-k8-grafana1-cabd0e-worker-0   Ready    node                   21d   v1.28.5   172.20.8.72    <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1160.108.1.el7.x86_64   containerd://1.6.16
prd-scl-it-k8-grafana1-cabd0e-worker-1   Ready    node                   21d   v1.28.5   172.20.8.171   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1160.108.1.el7.x86_64   containerd://1.6.16
prd-scl-it-k8-grafana1-cabd0e-worker-2   Ready    node                   21d   v1.28.5   172.20.8.47    <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1160.108.1.el7.x86_64   containerd://1.6.16

when I try to access service in my browser, its not working. I am trying below url (IP belongs to the worker)
http://172.20.8.47:8090
http://172.20.8.47:31000
can someone suggest what I may be doing wrong.
thanks

please specify the command you use for port-forwarding. with port numbers

kubectl --namespace monitoring port-forward $POD_NAME 3000

Added an answer, please try

tht didnt work. Also, if you see the cluster IP, Grafana is already exposed on port 80. doesn't matter if I forward it to port 3000 or any other now?

My mistake, sorry

Does the pod have this label? app: my-grafana-5b7dbf77b7-bzhxb of the service selector. Everything under selector are labels that Pods need to have in order to be selected by the service. In your example it seems you have put the pod name instead

to troubleshoot where is the porblem:
try to expose grafana to another service without ports ( it should do by itself as proper)
"kubectl expose pod your-pod-name --name=web-srv2 --type=NodePort"
then via "kubectl get svc" check opened nodeport and try to connect to it.
